# Similar to XmlSchemaProvider for JSON in WebAPI?

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, json.net, jsonschema

Is there any option in WebAPI to dynamically publish a model from a JSON schema? With web services, XmlSchemaProvider Serialize option provided the capability to publish a schema at runtime as the wsdl

Comment: Yes, using Swagger and swashbuckle  [have a look to this post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25668328/generate-json-schema-for-asp-net-web-api

Comment: Thanks, not the same. XmlSchemaProvider is not for documentation.

Comment: There is [Json.NET Schema](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema) (AGPL-3.0-only) and [JsonSchema.Net](https://gregsdennis.github.io/json-everything/usage/schema-overview.html) (MIT).