# Generate JSON Schema for ASP.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, jsonschema

I'm looking to generate JSON Schema for a WebAPI, including documentation from the XML comments.
Its primarily so that I can then import that into our API docs (using apiary.io)
I've managed to get a workaround solution by adding swagger (and swashbuckle) and then using the raw link on each service - but ideally I'd like something a bit cleaner, that works across all apis (this has to be done per service / controller), and didnt have so many dependencies.

Before I go and look at how swagger is doing this and seeing if it can be extracted, would be good to know if there are existing ways to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can depend on Swagger and there is extension for it named swashbuckle which you can use it with Web API easily, check this post http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/25/asp-net-web-api-documentation-using-swagger/